# publish json roslib

Tags: ros, roslib, rosbridge-server, roslibjs

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a dictionary and I tried to `JSON.stringify()` to turn it into a string which looks like this: `{"p_01_08":{},"p_01_09":{},"p_01_10":{},"p_01_11":{},"p_01_12":{},"p_01_13":{},"p_01_14":{},"p_02_07":{},"p_02_08":{},"p_02_09":{},"p_02_10":{},"p_02_11":{},"p_02_12":{},"p_02_13":{},"p_02_14":{},"p_02_15":{},"p_03_07":{},"p_03_08":{},"p_03_09":{},"p_03_10":{},"p_03_11":{},"p_03_12":{},"p_03_13":{},"p_03_14":{},"p_03_15":{},"p_04_07":{},"p_04_08":{},"p_04_09":{},"p_04_10":{},"p_04_11":{},"p_04_12":{},"p_04_13":{},"p_04_14":{},"p_04_15":{},"p_05_07":{},"p_05_08":{},"p_05_09":{},"p_05_10":{},"p_05_11":{},"p_05_12":{},"p_05_13":{},"p_05_14":{},"p_05_15":{},"p_06_07":{},"p_06_08":{},"p_06_09":{},"p_06_10":{},"p_06_11":{},"p_06_12":{},"p_06_13":{},"p_06_14":{},"p_06_15":{},"p_07_08":{},"p_07_09":{},"p_07_10":{},"p_07_11":{},"p_07_12":{},"p_07_13":{},"p_07_14":{}}`

Then I tried to use `roslib.js` to publish that Dictionary string:

```
import {store} from './store.js';
import { Ros, Message, Topic } from "roslib";

export default class ROSInterface {
  constructor() {
    this.ros = new Ros({
      url: "ws://localhost:9090",
    });
  }

  createMessage = (msg_data) => {
    const msg = new Message(msg_data);
    return msg;
  }

  createTopic = (topic_name, msg_type) => {
    const topic_ = new Topic({
      ros: this.ros,
      name: topic_name,
      messageType: msg_type,
    });
    return topic_;
  }

init=()=> {
  this.model_topic = this.createTopic('/model', 'std_msgs/String');
  this.lego_map_topic = this.createTopic('/lego_map', 'std_msgs/String');
  this.rate = 10; // 10hz
}

publish=()=> {
  this.interval = setInterval(this.publish_topics, 1000/this.rate)
}

publish_topics=()=> {
  // model
  console.log(JSON.stringify(store.model));
  let model_msg_ = this.createMessage(JSON.stringify(store.model));
  this.model_topic.publish(model_msg_);
  // lego_map
  let lego_map_msg_ = this.createMessage(JSON.stringify(store.lego_map));
  this.model_topic.publish(lego_map_msg_);
}

stopPublish=()=> {
  clearInterval(this.interval);
}
}
```

But Whenever I use the `publish()` method I get the following error on the `rosbridge server` terminal `roslaunch rosbridge_server rosbridge_websocket.launch`:
`publish: Message type std_msgs/String does not have a field 0`, Can you please tell me how can I advertise and publish the topic correctly? thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/411492/publish-json-roslib/) by [bhomaidan](https://answers.ros.org/users/71460/bhomaidan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 114 on 2023-01-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Perhaps there is a flaw in the way the message was created.
You may be successful if you try the following
std_msgs/String has the string in a field called data, not the string itself.

```
// const msg = new Message(msg_data);
const msg = new Message({ data: msg_data});
```

---

Originally posted by [miura](https://answers.ros.org/users/59801/miura/) with karma: 1908 on 2023-01-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0